# Accessibility of html elements that change innerHTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have this number credibility counter on my site that as the user scrolls, the headings with numbers count upwards from zero to the final total. I think it's an eye-catching way of showing off credibility, but as far as accessibility goes, I don't know if dynamically changing the numbers with JavaScript will confuse people who use screen readers. I thought about adding an "aria-labeledby" attribute to the heading so that the screen reader will read that instead of the dynamically changing text, but all of my google searches say that headings don't need aria labels, because screen readers will read the text inside the heading tags.
My question is if I add an "aria-labeledby" attribute to the heading, will that mess up how screen readers read the element?

Comment: `aria-labelledby` or `aria-label` will take precedence over the content so adding it is fine. But cant you just hide the number with `aria-hidden` because it looks like the numbers are more for an extra visual effect rather then having a functional purpose

Comment: People who use screen readers, probably have rather little interest in any extra "eye candy" to begin with. I did not get _exactly_ what the purpose of this feature is supposed to be, from your rather vague description - but it doesn't sound as if this was in any way _essential_ information, but probably rather the opposite. So you might actually be doing screen reader users a bigger favor, if you _hide_ this "noise" from them to begin with.

Comment: [The first rule of ARIA is ... use native HTML where you can](https://www.a11y-collective.com/the-first-rule-for-using-aria/).

Comment: That makes sense. Yes, it is definitely an eye candy feature, so I think using aria-hidden="true" is my best option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You normally don't need to do anything special.
Given that JavaScript is supported in the user's browser, the text of the heading will also change dynamically for screen readers, too.

That dynamic change in content may be problematic for screen readers if it isn't reasonably expected.
More especially, for example, when something currently being read is suddenly replaced by something else or completely deleted without user intervention.
A common case of this is a carousel with content that changes every few seconds. Such carousels are usually bad for accessibility if they can't be easily stopped because of this reason among others.

However, in your case, for a simple counter, it's probably all right. There probably won't have much harm.

Attributes aria-label and aria-labelledby can only be used reliably with interactive elements that can be focusable.
ON non-interactive elements, it isn't guaranteed to have them read on all platforms/browsers/screen readers.
So, it's anyway not a good solution here.